# Need help with a Test class coverage

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

Hello guys i need help to cover this Trigger on a Test Class, this Test Class also covers another class so some Data is not refering to the Trigger.

This is the Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class OnInvoiceTriggerHelper_Test {

 @isTest 
    static void teste_invoiceHeadersEMAIL(){
        Email_Engine__c setting = Email_Engine__c.getOrgDefaults();


        system.debug('Custom Setting Before: ' + setting);
        setting.Email_Engine__c = String.valueOf(Turned_On__c);
        upsert setting;

        Account novaConta = new Account(
            Name = 'TESTE Account',
            Enqix_Payment_Method__c='Account'
        );
        insert novaConta;

        Account novaConta2 = new Account(
            Name = 'TESTE Account 2',
            Enqix_Payment_Method__c='Account'
        );
        insert novaConta2;
        system.debug('CONTA NOVA ' + novaConta);


        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.AccountId = novaConta2.id;
        c.Email = 'jessica3pereira@gmail.com';
        c.Contact_Role__c = 'Finance Contact';
        c.LastName = 'Carvalho';
        c.FirstName = 'Nuno';
        insert c;
        system.debug(c);



        AccountContactRelation novaRelation = new AccountContactRelation(
            AccountId = novaConta.Id,
            ContactId = c.Id,
            Roles = 'Finance Contact; Influencer'

        );
        insert novaRelation;

        Invoice_Header__c header = new Invoice_Header__c(
            Name = 'TESTE header',
            Account__c = novaConta.Id,
            AmountExclVAT__c = 199,
            Status__c = 'Normal',
            Salesforce__c = false
        );
        insert header;
        Invoice_Header__c headerInserido = [Select Id, ToPublish__c, Account__c, Status__c, AmountExclVAT__c from Invoice_Header__c Where Id = :header.Id];
        //system.debug('Header novo '+ header + ' ToPublish está a true? = ' + header.ToPublish__c);
        system.debug('Header novo '+ headerInserido + ' ToPublish está a true? = ' + headerInserido.ToPublish__c);



        }
}
```

This is the Trigger:

```
trigger InvoiceHeaderTrigger on Invoice_Header__c (after insert, after update) {
    InvoiceHeaderTriggerHelper.continueInvoice(trigger.new);

            List<Invoice_Header__c> headersReadyToBeEmailed = new List<Invoice_Header__c>();
    //Verificar a custom set “Email Engine” e ver se o campo “turned on” está true ou não. E só envia se estiver a true. Turned_On__c 
    Email_Engine__c ee = Email_Engine__c.getOrgDefaults();
    system.debug(ee.Turned_On__c);
    if(ee.Turned_On__c == true){
        system.debug('entrou');
        for(Invoice_Header__c h : trigger.new){
            if(h.Status__c != 'Draft' && h.Status__c != 'Emailed' && h.ToPublish__c == true && h.AmountExclVAT__c > 0){
                headersReadyToBeEmailed.add(h);**
            }
        }
    }

    if(headersReadyToBeEmailed.size()>0){
        InvoiceHeaderTriggerHelper.InvoiceEmail(headersReadyToBeEmailed);
    }

}
```

The lines of the trigger that did not get covered were:

```
for(Invoice_Header__c h : trigger.new){
            if(h.Status__c != 'Draft' && h.Status__c != 'Emailed' && h.ToPublish__c == true && h.AmountExclVAT__c > 0){
                headersReadyToBeEmailed.add(h);
```

---

```
InvoiceHeaderTriggerHelper.InvoiceEmail(headersReadyToBeEmailed);
```

Comment: Can you please be specific about which lines are you unable to cover?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Your test code does not seem like it would even compile. Specifically this line: `setting.Email_Engine__c = String.valueOf(Turned_On__c);`

Answer (score 5):

I think this can be solved by some basic debugging. Let's approach this by working backwards.

The second line of code you indicate as uncovered is in an `if` block that depends on the first section of code you indicate as uncovered.

Looking at the first section of uncovered code, we see this:

```
if(ee.Turned_On__c == true){
    system.debug('entrou');
    for(Invoice_Header__c h : trigger.new){
        if(h.Status__c != 'Draft' && h.Status__c != 'Emailed' && h.ToPublish__c == true && h.AmountExclVAT__c > 0){
            headersReadyToBeEmailed.add(h);**
        }
    }
}
```

if `ee.Turned_On__c == true` evaluates to false, then you won't enter the `if` block, leading to your for loop not being executed (and hence, not covered). (As a side note, `if(booleanVariable == true)` can be replaced with `if(booleanVariable)`

So, this variable `ee` is a suspect. What is this variable?
Looking up one more line, we see `Email_Engine__c ee = Email_Engine__c.getOrgDefaults();`

`ee` is a hierarchy custom setting, and hierarchy custom settings need to be inserted as part of the test setup.

Now, let's look at the setup for your unit test.

```
Email_Engine__c setting = Email_Engine__c.getOrgDefaults();

system.debug('Custom Setting Before: ' + setting);
setting.Email_Engine__c = String.valueOf(Turned_On__c);
upsert setting;
```

I don't see you setting the value of `setting.Turned_On__c` anywhere here, so that must be your issue. Your code requires this value to be true to actually execute the bulk of your code. I also don't see a `Turned_On__c` variable declared anywhere, which makes me think that your test class shouldn't compile.

Some parting advice:

- You need to determine what the output of running this trigger should be, and make *assertions* to verify that your trigger does, in fact, cause the thing you expect to happen to actually happen. For all you know, without assertions, your code could say that 2 + 2 = fish (which would likely cause issues elsewhere)
- It's a good idea to have more than one unit test. Instead of worrying about coverage, worry about the different situations your code will possibly need to handle. What happens if variable `x` is null? What happens if this query doesn't return any records? If you write tests to cover enough situations, your coverage will naturally be high.

Comment: Maybe add some parting advice about getting that logic out of the dang trigger body. :)